# type of data to be send between android and RESTful ws

Tags: java, android, mysql, hibernate, rest

i have a  android APP + RESTful(jersey) + mysql.
i need to send (image +name+description) from android app to RESTfull and store it in the mysql using hibernate.

and vise versa i need to receive the same by my android APP.
i know that the data exchange between the app and the service should be in JSON format .

but what i want to know is what type of data should i use in every part.
i mean for example.  by what type should i store the image in mysql.
and how to encode and decode the image to that type.

i tried to use String and that's work fine but i think it's not a good way.

thank you.

Comment: so at the end that's what i did
encode the image with base64 in android app and pass it to jsonobject and send it to the ws
and vise versa when receiving it 
store the image as varchar(4000) in mysql 

so there is no modifying in server side just within the android app
if this is the right hope this answer will help someone and if it's not correct it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send the image from the android app as a `String` in `jsonobject` by encoding it by `base64` since you don't need to view the image on the web service,you can store the image as `varchar(4000)` in mysql , when the app ask the service for the image the service send him the same string that was send by the app and it's super easy to decode the string back to image by `base64.`

of course you can send whatever information you want with the image in the `jsonobject`